# What is the name of this discipline in mathematics education?

Tags: algebra, functions, number-theory

I am struggling with my students who can think only in concrete terms,

they can compute with concrete numbers but are not able to think in terms of e.g. functions on natural numbers and come up with a general solution.

This cognitive skill would be needed when I teach them writing a function in a programming language.

I tried to search for teaching abstraction but that gave me mostly hits about programming.

I want to find math teaching articles that would help me teaching this.

What is the name of this subdiscipline in math education?

Comment: Maybe google with terms associated with [Piaget's stages of mental development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piaget%27s_theory_of_cognitive_development)?

Comment: The [Van Hiele levels](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10352) discuss five stages of mathematical understanding, but [omit an important one](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10352#10356):  The ability to construct new shapes or ideas using more basic ones.

Comment: Another question on this site asks, "[Is there a Piagetian age at which proofs can be comprehended?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7912)"

Comment: Some related topics include "[Introducing the concept of variables to kids](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/12206)", "[When should we first teach variables in school math? And how?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10206)", and "[How do I teach algebra?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1834)"  Two key concepts are "[*x* is just a number you don't know yet](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1834/#1840)", and "[check your work](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1834#1861)" (a.k.a. "Unit Testing").

Comment: There are functions as algorithms and functions as relations. What type of functions do you want to teach?

Comment: @beroal math functions, to be able to teach algorithmic functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the name of this subdiscipline in math education?

In one of the comments, **Dave L Renfro** has a reference to Piaget, whose work was primarily done with younger schoolchildren. With respect to extending this work into the older years of one's education, a potentially good place to look would be **APOS Theory**, which is due to Ed Dubinsky and collaborators. For an introduction, see [**APOS: A Constructivist Theory of Learning in Undergraduate Mathematics Education Research**](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6850/b01648bf43e15cbdbcf871b215c3cf44825d.pdf) (pdf) by Dubinsky and Michael McDonald.

More generally, you might search out additional information on APOS theory using [**google scholar**](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=APOS+Theory&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C33&as_sdtp=).

As pertains to your description:

> they can compute with concrete numbers but are not able to think in terms of e.g. functions on natural numbers and come up with a general solution

These students are probably at either the **A**ction level, or, if they are carrying out these computations in an algorithmic, procedural way, then they may be at the **P**rocesses level. (The final two letters stand for **O**bjects and **S**chemas; more can be found in the first link, above, as well as in its references.)